# Issue with VBA SaveAs method for Powerpoint files

Tags: vba, save, powerpoint, save-as

I'm having an issue on my VBA script.
I am doing some modifications on PPT tables.

At the end of the script, I want to save modifications and here is the issue.

To do the saving, I use the following command to save the file in a specific folder:

```
PptDoc.SaveAs (ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "result" & Application.PathSeparator & sFilename
```

(PptDoc is a PowerPoint.Presentation)

Everything works fine at the execution. File is correctly saved at the correct address. Then when I want to launch the ppt, file is corrupted I can't open it.
I don't know what to do, I haven't found anything on Google.

Here are some precisions :

- I am working with Excel/PowerPoint 2011 for Mac ;
- my script modifies content of tables of existing powerpoint files (30) ;
- when I save my work manually, it work and there is no error later

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution,

Correct command is :

```
PptDoc.SaveAs (ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "result" & Application.PathSeparator & sFilename, ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation
```

By default, it chooses the format equivalent to .ppt but my file was a .pptx. ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation means .pptx whereas ppSaveAsDefault or ppSaveAsPresentation means .ppt.

Hope this will help people having the same issue

:)